# Downloading a Word Document Template from attachment

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I am unable to download the doc file from attachment. It says that file is corrupted.

If file is attached manually in Attachment section, then it is working fine but when file is attached in Attachment section using Document Generation feature then my console app is unable to download it correctly.

It says file is corrupted and it's size is also 2 KB which is incorrect.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

Using c#, I have retrieved the annotation. Then like below:

```
var filebody_ = NotesAttachment.GetAttributeValue<string>("documentbody"); 
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(filebody); 
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\DOCS\Test.docx", bytes);
```

1. Doc file which we generally upoad in CRM through CRM UI by browsing
   it. This type of doc is getting saved correctly in my local disk if
   we run the above code.
2. Doc file which got generated through "Document Generation". This
   doc is not getting saved correctly in my local disk.

Comment: Just to be clear: You're trying to download an attachment in an Annotation, that has been generated from a Word template, correct?

Comment: Post some code!

Comment: Using c#, I have retrieved the annotation. Then like below:
                    var filebody_ = _NotesAttachment.GetAttributeValue<string>("documentbody");
  byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(filebody_);
   File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\DOCS\Test.docx", bytes);

Above code is creating corrupt DOC only when this attachment is attached through system WF using Action:SetTemplate

Comment: @gnud: Trying to download an attachment(doc file) from annotation entity into local folder.

Comment: @ACRM My point was that you're not trying to download the template, but a document generated from a template. OK. Does these documents work as expected when downloading them normally through the browser?

Comment: Yes, that works normally.

Comment: So you're downloading an Annotation from CRM, saving it to local disk and then uploading it back to CRM as an email attachment? Is the file in local disk saved correctly (i.e. can you go to `c:\users\docs\test.docx` and open the document)

Comment: No, file in local disk is not saved correctly and that is the issue.
1. Doc file which we generally upoad in CRM through CRM UI by browsing it. This type of doc is getting saved correctly in my local disk if we run the above code.
2. Doc file which got generated through "Document Generation" OOB. This doc is not getting saved correctly in my local disk.

Comment: It had issue while fetching using Fetch XML, same query I did through Query Expression and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that if we fetch the Annotations using **Fetch XML**, due to it's limitation in column size, above code is not able to save the attachment (word doc) in correct format.

Here, if we fetch the annotations using **Query Expression**, it's return type is something different and the above code is able to save the attachment (word doc) in correct format.

So, I changed the way of query and it worked for me.

Others have faced this issue [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscrmbestpractices/archive/2017/09/03/crm-issue-with-retrieving-large-document-body-using-fetch-xml-solution).